# SQL Sub rows - UNION vs JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, union, rows

i would like to join 2 table but not duplicating all data.

try to be more clear
I have table_A

```
 | ID | Description | Total 
 | 1. | Test a.     | 10
 | 2. | Test B.     |  8
```

and my total is 18

Table_B

```
|ID| Site
|1 | Site A
|1 | Site B
|2 | Site C
```

If i do a left

```sql
Select a.ID,a.Description,b.Site,a.Total from table_a as a 
left outer join table_b as b on a.id =b.it
```

i get

```
 | ID | Description | Site  | Total 
 | 1. | Test a.     | Site A|. 10
 | 1. | Test a.     | Site B|. 10
 | 2. | Test B.     | Site C|  8
```

so my total became 28

i would like to get something like

```
 | a.ID |b.ID| Description | Site  | Total 
 | 1.   |    | Test a.     |       |. 10
 | 1.   |  1 |             | Site A|
 | 1.   |  1 |             | Site B| 
 | 2.   |    | Test B.     |       |  8
 | 2.   |  2 |             | Site C|
```

so i can have it in excel and create a group by into the row

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. There are a few methods of doing this, one is using a `UNION` to get the 2 datasets:

```sql
SELECT aID,
       bID,
       description,
       Site,
       Total
FROM (SELECT a.ID AS aID,
             b.ID AS bID,
             a.description,
             b.Site,
             NULL AS Total
      FROM dbo.TableA a
           JOIN dbo.TableB b ON A.ID = B.ID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a.ID AS aID,
             NULL,
             a.description,
             NULL,
             a.Total
      FROM dbo.TableA a) U
ORDER BY aID,
         bID,
         Site;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a4a30137aff339a360b0f3527a921b9)